# How can resolve 'Undeclared identifier' during withdraw from smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I created an array of each address and amount of all users who have previously deposited a certain amount of ETH, then used the 'transfer' function (within : retireMyCoins()) to retrieve the amount and address of the user who is using the contract from the list. The user can then withdraw his ETH.

When compiling the contract, in the last function "retireMyCoins" the console returns the following error: 'Undeclared identifier'.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract myVault {
                     
    address[] public users;                      
    uint[] public totalDeposited;                

    function sendToken(address user, uint amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.001 ether);      
        
        user = msg.sender;                      
        amount = msg.value;  

        users.push(msg.sender);                 
        totalDeposited.push(msg.value);        

    }

    function getUsers() public view returns (address[]) {    
        return users;
    }

    function getAmount() public view returns (uint[]) {
        return totalDeposited;
    }

    function retireMyCoins() public {
        require(user[msg.sender]); 
        require(amount[msg.value]); 
        user.transfer(this.amount); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create amount as a store variable in the beginning of your contract. Also, to make it work as you expect, you should map the balance of each user, like the following:

```
...
mapping( address => uint ) balances;
function sendToken(address user, uint amount) public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = amount;
...
}
```

and then you can allow the withdrawal:

```
function retireMyCoins() public {
   uint amountToWithdraw = balances[msg.sender]
   balances[msg.sender] = 0; 
   msg.sender.transfer(amountToWithdraw); 
}
```

Remember to zero the user balance before the transfer as above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried to implement as you suggested. Unfortunately, there are problems in the retire coins phase. The contract fails to return the amount paid to the user and the ethers are stuck inside with no way to withdraw them.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was because it was transfering 0 ether. First you should save the amount on a variable and then transfer that variable. Just be careful to set the balance to 0 before the transfer as otherwise could lead to reentrancy issues. I editted the answer, it should work now. Also, that a look on the variables scope and mappings for solidity, should help you out

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I cleaned up my code which now works thanks to your suggestions. I then created a store variable 'uint256 balance = balances[msg.sender];' at the beginning of my contract. Then inside the store function I inserted 'balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;' which saves the value inside the variable for each transfer. Finally I concluded by inserting the function 'retireMyCoins' which allows each user to withdraw their balance. Thank you I am already looking in depth at the mappings and variable scopes.